# I am running my onos with bazel but keep getting Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >< - expected >JDWP-Handshake

Tags: jvm, bazel, handshake, mininet, onos

I am using onos 2.7.1 with bazel-6.0.0-pre20220421.3 and after build with bazel and running it, my onos log file shows Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Sep 15, 2023 12:31:29 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main launch
INFO: Installing and starting initial bundles
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >< - expected >JDWP-Handshake<
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >< - expected >JDWP-Handshake<
Sep 15, 2023 12:31:30 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main launch

How can I resolve this

I have tried to locate the jvm folder to no avail as I so a fix on https://gist.github.com/zedar/82f10d1064b00cbea79d